# Passing boolean parameters in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, curl, boolean

My Ruby on Rails function should receive a boolean parameter, check it and, if it is true, do something.

```
  def isReady
     if (params[:ready] == true)
            doSomething()
     end
  end
```

However, with the example below we never get inside this if (but it enters the function), probably because the parameter is passed as a string instead of as a boolean. How can I pass boolean parameters properly, or convert them?

```
curl --data "ready=true" http://example.com/users/isReady
```

Comment: @Marting has a good answer, Coz when u pass parameters over http(s) it goes as string. This is just a off the topic comment :), in ruby use as `def ready?` instead of `def isReady`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> probably because the parameter is passed as a string instead of as a boolean.

Correct. The way I handle this in *generic* Ruby way is as follows:

```
class String
  def to_b()
    self.downcase == "true"
  end
end
```

Now any string will have the `to_b` method. You can you write

```
def ready?
  if params[:ready].to_b
    do_something
  end
end
```